# Fat Jar expands dependencies with Gradle Kotlin DSL

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I am trying to build a fat jar using the following in my Kotlin based gradle file.

```kotlin
val fatJar = task("fatJar", type = Jar::class) {
  baseName = "safescape-lib-${project.name}"
  // manifest Main-Class attribute is optional.
  // (Used only to provide default main class for executable jar)
  from(configurations.runtimeClasspath.map({ if (it.isDirectory) it else zipTree(it) }))
  with(tasks["jar"] as CopySpec)
}

tasks {
  "build" {
    dependsOn(fatJar)
  }
}
```

However, the fat jar has all the dependencies expanded out. I would like to have the jars included as is in a /lib directory but I cannot work out how to achieve this.

Can anyone give any pointers as to how I can achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you are using `zipTree` in that `map` part of the spec, and it behaves according to [the documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/5.4.1/dsl/org.gradle.api.Script.html#org.gradle.api.Script:zipTree(java.lang.Object)): it unzips the files that are not a directory.

If you want the jars in `/lib`, replace your `from` with:

```kotlin
from(configurations.runtimeClasspath) {
    into("lib")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is using `kotlin-multiplatform` plugin, the configuration is a bit different. Here's a `fatJar` task configuration assuming JVM application with embedded JS frontend from JS module:

```kotlin
afterEvaluate {
  tasks {
    create("jar", Jar::class).apply {
      dependsOn("jvmMainClasses", "jsJar")
      group = "jar"
      manifest {
        attributes(
          mapOf(
            "Implementation-Title" to rootProject.name,
            "Implementation-Version" to rootProject.version,
            "Timestamp" to System.currentTimeMillis(),
            "Main-Class" to mainClassName
          )
        )
      }
      val dependencies = configurations["jvmRuntimeClasspath"].filter { it.name.endsWith(".jar") } +
          project.tasks["jvmJar"].outputs.files +
          project.tasks["jsJar"].outputs.files
      dependencies.forEach { from(zipTree(it)) }
      into("/lib")
    }
  }
}
```